# Using C++ DLLs in a browser

Tags: c++, dll, web-applications, client-side, emscripten

We have a .DLL library generated from a huge C++ project. We would like to expose it over the web.

The first attempt was to use Emscripten. But I guess based on [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668931/using-libraries-with-emscripten), not every library could be linked with JavaScript.

What we would like to have is a client-side application. The reason is security and performance. The application is highly interactive which makes it almost impossible to implement in a client-server fashion. The security reason is that as a part of interactions users can access the underlying hardware resources, thus hosting it on a server is risky.

Is there any way to make this happen? I just want to know if there are other options available, or whether a solution using Emscripten is available.

P.S: We have the source code for our C++ library, but the code itself uses many other libraries.

Comment: It is not entirely understandable what you mean by exposing over the web - simply the ability to run it in a browser on the same machine where the dll is hosted or have a client html interface that would still connect to some server?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, our preference is to have the ability to run it in a browser on the same machine where the dll is hosted. As I said, since the library provides low-level hardware access, we prefer not to run it on a remote machine

Comment: well then why browser instead of an ordinary application with a GUI that loads the DLL? Any particular reason?

Comment: We actually want to integrate it with another web-based application.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. Well anyways, an alternative would be that you can use node.js - node.js binds to C++ very easily so if you expose yourself to node.js and then run a thin node server that would connect to the other application that you need to integrate with either via web sockets or ajax requests I think you can achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks @RudolfsBundulis. So, from what I understand the whole thing can be linked against JavaScript but run as a windows application. right? so, sooner or later, Emscripten should be able to integrate this to be used in a web browser in similar way.

Comment: Not sure about Emscripten since it involves generating JavaScript while node.js simply offers a way to bind calls to C++. I'll try to post a complete answer with more details, but I assume this could be what you need (or maybe not if I haven't got some details right).

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, I might wait to see if anyone else has any idea on this, but otherwise that would be a proper answer. Thank you!

Comment: Of course there may be better approaches:) I simply offered this since I am using this combo as well to expose a functionality of a DLL to  javascript in an html frontend and so far it has worked very well.

Comment: I would like to see the detailed description whenever you have time.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach would be to expose the API from your DLL to Node.js via [C++ bindings](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Consider the following example from the documentation:

```
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, init)
```

Basically in the `init` function you can expose all the entry functions to your DLL which can further either return primitive types like strings, numbers etc. or even wrapped C++ objects (however so far I've been sticking with the primitives to escape modifying the existing code, as long as you stick with primitive types you just need to translate the C++ types to v8). So this C++ code would yo allow to do the following from javascript:

```
var object = require('./build/Release/addon');
console.log(addon.hello()); // 'world'
```

Since you need to communicate with some other web based application then your node.js code would most likely bind to a port on the same machine and process ajax requests or web socket calls from the application you are integrating with and then forward what is needed to the functions exposed from the DLL.

Comment: Thanks, but this is re-writing the library! How can I link it to an existing librarY?

Comment: Well, there is no need to rewrite anything, you just need to add glue code that exposes the API - you don't need to change anything in the existing code. But this may be an aspect I didn't understand - so you want to use the existing binaries and avoid compiling anything?

Comment: Alright now I get it. It might be possible to change it just to add the glue code. Ideal was to avoid compiling, but that should also work.

Comment: Well I understand that it would be a perfect solution if there was a technology that would just take the binaries you have however I'm not aware of any such thing:) But if there is nothing better (and I am not claiming there isn't) some glue code is not the worst thing that can happen.

Comment: What I actually meant by that is to write a helper C++ code that uses the compiled DLL as a library and do the fancy thing over that helper. So, I think it should be possible to write the glue code in that helper file and through that access the DLL components. right?

Comment: Yes, that is another way and then you don't have to recompile the original DLL.